# How to insert a substring before the first match in regular expressions in Golang?

Tags: regex, go

I have a regex as following `(ORDER\s+BY)|(LIMIT)|$`. I want to insert a substring before the first match of the regex. I am looking for a pure regexp solution in Golang not finding the index and then adding a substring. Since Golang only has regexp.ReplaceAll func which replaces all the matches, not the first one.

```
exp := regexp.MustCompile(`(ORDER\s+BY)|(LIMIT)|$`)
fmt.Println(exp.ReplaceAllString(str, "..."))
```

Example

Input: `abcd ORDER BY LIMIT` substring=`GROUP BY`

Expected output: `abcd GROUP BY ORDER BY LIMIT`

Input: `abcd LIMIT`

Expected output: `abcd GROUP BY LIMIT`

Comment: ``regexp.MustCompile(`^(.*?)(ORDER\s+BY|LIMIT|$)`).ReplaceAllString(str, "${1}GROUP BY ${2}")``, see [this demo](https://play.golang.org/p/f4lIEdvA7IP).

Comment: Thanks alot that solves it. If you would answer it, I could close it. @WiktorStribiżew

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use

```
str := "abcd ORDER BY LIMIT"
exp := regexp.MustCompile(`^(.*?)(ORDER\s+BY|LIMIT|$)`)
fmt.Println(exp.ReplaceAllString(str, "${1}GROUP BY ${2}"))
```

If there can be line breaks before the pattern use `(?s)` in front: `(?s)^(.*?)(ORDER\s+BY|LIMIT|$)`.

See the [Go demo](https://play.golang.org/p/FAR-V_Xzc8G) and the [regex graph](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(.*%3F)(ORDER%5Cs%2BBY%7CLIMIT%7C%24)):

[image]

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(.*?)` - Group 1 (`${1}`): any 0+ chars, as few as possible
- `(ORDER\s+BY|LIMIT|$)` - Group 2 (`${2}`): any of the three alternatives, whichever comes first:

  - `ORDER\s+BY` - `ORDER`, 1+ whitespaces, `BY`
  - `LIMIT` - a `LIMIT` substring
  - `$` - end of string.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that this expression might work here:

```
(ORDER\s+BY\s+LIMIT|LIMIT)$
```

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/1oLPOo/1/)

#### Test

```
package main

import (
    "regexp"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    var re = regexp.MustCompile(`(?m)(ORDER\s+BY\s+LIMIT|LIMIT)$`)
    var str = `abcd ORDER BY LIMIT
abcd LIMIT`
    var substitution = "GROUP BY $1"

    fmt.Println(re.ReplaceAllString(str, substitution))
}
```

Comment: Why did you change the original expression? OP does not need to change it, only add text before the first occurrence of the pattern. Besides, `ReplaceAllString` replaces all matches.